# (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 22021 (character_not_in_repertoire): invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x92

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, elixir, ecto, postgrex

I'm saving HTML from various websites on the internet and saving it to a simple Postgres `text` field.

This is the error I'm getting:

> ** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 22021 (character_not_in_repertoire): invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x92

What would be a quick workaround for this? I don't really care about losing some data but would prefer not to.

Comment: The HTTP response should contain a Content-Type header telling you what text encoding is being used, you need to use that.

Comment: @AlexK. I'm not sure how to do that in Elixir - can you flesh out your answer a bit? Appreciate it!

Comment: What library are you using to call the websites?